# Shopify checkout process

Tags: css, shopify, checkout

Shopify used to allow you to style the checkout process through a CSS file. However, they have now removed this option.

I've developed a Shopify App for a customer that requires that ALL customers digitally sign a form before payment. The form asks specific questions, and must be presented in a specific way, with a specific font. In their country it is illegal to sell online without sending your customers through this process. Everything is sent over TLS etc.

On the form, a customer is asked their name, delivery address, billing address, etc. The products are listed and followed by a ton of legal text.

The difficulty is, as soon as the customer goes to checkout - they are then able to change their delivery and billing address, thus rendering the form null and void.

My initial thought was to simply hide the customer billing and delivery information from the checkout using CSS. However, I'm unable to do this because Shopify no longer grant access to the style sheet.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: Hey @Rob maybe you wanna take a look at this: http://exclusive-checkout-demo.myshopify.com

Comment: I built a very similar thing - but was told it could not be released in the app store. I'm still a bit annoyed about it. It basically replaced Shopify's checkout and added single use discount codes.

Comment: can I see it? dm me please at a@alexandresaiz.com